# How to force UFW to be enabled after every restart (currently "inactive")?

Tags: startup, firewall, ufw, restart

I have enabled the UFW in terminal using "sudo ufw enable" ... But, UFW does not appear to start when the computer starts.

After the computer starts, I check the status of the UFW using "sudo ufw status verbose" ... I expect to see "Status: active" in terminal but, instead, I am seeing "Status: inactive".

How do I force the UFW to run at startup?

Thanks.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345505/65110 worked for me.

Comment: I cannot start an answer but perhaps someone will copy this comment out, I solved the problem by using supervisor with https://docs.syncthing.net/users/autostart.html as an example and running `/etc/init.d/ufw start` as root after having already tried the answer from @Pradeeper to no improvement.

Answer (score 7):

Edit your /etc/ufw/ufw.conf and make,

```
ENABLED=yes
```

Comment: this did not work for me, and I also set ENABLED=yes in /usr/share/ufw/ufw.conf

Comment: neither worked for me